# RoomDatabase: cannot find symbole variable _result

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, androidx, android-livedata

I'm trying to make a research on my RoomDatabase with @RawQuery and SupportSQLiteQuery. 
I have this error : "cannot fin symbole variable _result" when building in PropertyDao_Impl. I already try to CleanProject and Rebuild several times.

Do you have an idea of what I'm doing wrong ?
Thanks in advance !

```
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.room.*
import androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteQuery
import com.openclassrooms.realestatemanager.add_edit.Property


@Dao
interface PropertyDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Property")
    fun getAllProperties(): LiveData<List<Property>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun addProperty(property: Property): Long

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Property WHERE id_property = :id_property")
    suspend fun getPropertyFromId(id_property: String): Property

    @RawQuery(observedEntities = [Property::class])
    fun searchInDatabase(query: SupportSQLiteQuery): MutableLiveData<List<Property>>
}
```

PropertyDao_Impl.java (generated) :

```
@Override
  public MutableLiveData<List<Property>> searchInDatabase(final SupportSQLiteQuery query) {
    final SupportSQLiteQuery _internalQuery = query;
    __db.assertNotSuspendingTransaction();
    final Cursor _cursor = DBUtil.query(__db, _internalQuery, false, null);
    try {
      return _result; // error here
    } finally {
      _cursor.close();
    }
  }
}
```

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.4"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.4"
```

Comment: You have to declare `_result`.

Comment: Hi. I can't modify PropertyDao_Impl, it's autogenerated

Comment: It should be `LiveData<List<` not `MutableLiveData`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thanks ! It was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
@RawQuery(observedEntities = [Property::class])
fun searchInDatabase(query: SupportSQLiteQuery): MutableLiveData<List<Property>>
```

with

```
@RawQuery(observedEntities = [Property::class])
fun searchInDatabase(query: SupportSQLiteQuery): LiveData<List<Property>>
```

Answer (score 0):

For short, if you are using Jetpack Paging library **v3.0.0+**, you have to update your version of Room too, **v2.3.0-rc01** worked for me.

Long answer.
This happened to me when I was trying to use Paging librar v3.0.0-beta03 & Room v2.2.6.

RoomEntityDAO

```
@RawQuery(observedEntities = [RoomEntity::class])
fun getOrdersDataSource(query: SupportSQLiteQuery): DataSource.Factory<Int, RoomEntity>
```

Generates in RoomEntityDAO_Impl

```
@Override
  public PagingSource<Integer, RoomEntity> getOrdersDataSource(
      final SupportSQLiteQuery query) {
    final SupportSQLiteQuery _internalQuery = query;
    __db.assertNotSuspendingTransaction();
    final Cursor _cursor = DBUtil.query(__db, _internalQuery, false, null);
    try {
      return _result;
    } finally {
      _cursor.close();
    }
  }
```

This question have already an accepted answer, but it might help some else having the same issue.

Comment: I updated my Room to 2.3.0 but I'm still having the same issue. I also originally only had LiveData rather than MutableLiveData anyway. Any ideas?

Edit: It works if I remove LiveData entirely... but then I don't have any LiveData, which seemingly defeats the point. Does the LiveData still work if I wrap the return of the raw query with MutableLiveData, like so?

`
suspend fun findAll(field: String, value: Any): LiveData<List<E>> = MutableLiveData(rawList(
        SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE $field = $value")
    ))
`

Comment: As I know a Room query that return a live data will not work if you add suspend keyword.